# Regex: how to keep a numeric string but adding other characters to the left and right

Tags: regex

I have some strings like

```
Tenet 2020
Alpha.1999
beta (1997)
```

I try to undestand how replace in this way

```
Tenet (2020)#
Alpha.(1999)#
beta (1997)#
```

**Find**: `(\d{4})|(\(\d+)\)`
**Replace**: `\(\1\)#`

This regex is not perfect because it removes `1997` from last string:

```
Tenet (2020)#
Alpha.(1999)#
beta ()#
```

Comment: That’s probably because in the last string, the match is not \1, but \2. Since only one of them can match, you should be ok in replacing it with \(\1\2\)#, because either \1 or \2 are empty.

Comment: I tried with `\((\1\2)\)#` but for last string it return me `beta ((1997)#` and not `beta (1997)#`

Comment: *facepalm* of course, I did not consider that... That is because the \2 includes the parentheses.
Try find: `(\d{4})|\((\d+)\)`, i.e. switching the escaped and unescaped parentheses in the 2nd case

Comment: Yes. now it works! Thank you !

Comment: What tool/language are you using? The regex will be different depending on regex flavour.

Comment: If your regex flavour supports `Branch Reset Group`, you can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/vHguMD/1)